# C++ std::vector::clear() crash

Tags: c++, stdvector

I've got a program where I have a std::vector as a member of a class:

```
class Blackboard
{
public:
    inline std::vector<Vector2<int> > GetPath()         
    { return m_path; }

    inline void SetPath(std::vector<Vector2<int> > path)
    { m_path = path; }

    inline void ClearPath()                                         
    { if(m_path.size() > 0) m_path.clear(); }

private:
    std::vector<Vector2<int>> m_path;
};
```

Where the Vector2 class is defined as:

```
template <class T>
class Vector2
{
private:
    T m_x;
    T m_y;

public:
    Vector2(void)
    { m_x = 0; m_y = 0;}

    Vector2(T x, T y)                                           
    { m_x = x; m_y = y;}

    ~Vector2(void)                                      
    { }

    inline T x() const                                  
    { return m_x; }

    inline T y() const                                  
    { return m_y; }

    // ...
};
```

And at some point I call:

```
m_blackboard.ClearPath();
```

This works fine in debug, but crashes in release with the "Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in Test2.exe." message.

The call stack, at the last point where I can still see shows that:

```
Test2.exe!std::vector<RBT::Vector2<int>,
std::allocator<RBT::Vector2<int> > >::erase
(std::_Vector_const_iterator<RBT::Vector2<int>,
std::allocator<RBT::Vector2<int> > > 
_First_arg={m_x=15 m_y=7 },
std::_Vector_const_iterator<RBT::Vector2<int>,
std::allocator<RBT::Vector2<int> > > 
_Last_arg={m_x=15 m_y=8 })  Line 1037 + 0xe bytes  C++
```

Here is where I'm calling the code that ends up crashing:

```
BTNode::Status GoToDestBehavior::Update()
{
    BTEntityData::Node* node = m_dataRef->m_bTree.GetNode(m_index);
    if(node->m_state == BTNode::STATE_READY)
    {
        BehaviorTree::RequestDeferredAction(Batch::PATHFIND, m_dataRef->m_entityID);
        return BTNode::STATE_RUNNING;
    }
    else if(node->m_state == BTNode::STATE_RUNNING)
    {
        std::vector<Vector2<int>>  path = m_dataRef->m_blackboard.GetPath();

        EntitySystem::Entity* entity = EntitySystem::GetEntity(m_dataRef->m_entityID);
        Assert(entity != NULL, "Invalid entity\n");

        Assert(entity->HasComponent(Component::PHYSICS_COMP), "Associated entity must have physics component to move\n");
        int phyIndex = entity->GetComponentIndex(Component::PHYSICS_COMP);

        PhysicsSystem::PhysicsData * physicsData = PhysicsSystem::GetComponent(phyIndex);
        Assert(physicsData != NULL, "Invalid physics data\n");

        // Path is empty, so finish
        if(path.size() == 0)
        {
            physicsData->m_dir = Direction::NONE;       // Stop because we are here
            return BTNode::STATE_SUCCESS;
        }

        // Remove last element if we are at it
        //LogFmt("Size of vector %d\n", path.size());
        Vector2<int> last = path.back();
        if(last.x() == physicsData->m_posX && last.y() == physicsData->m_posY)
        {
            path.pop_back();
        }

        // Last node of the path has been transversed
        if(path.size() == 0)
        {
            physicsData->m_dir = Direction::NONE;       // Stop because we are here
            m_dataRef->m_blackboard.ClearPath();
            return BTNode::STATE_SUCCESS;
        }

        Vector2<int> step = path.back();                

        physicsData->m_dir = Direction::VectorToDirection(physicsData->m_posX, physicsData->m_posY, step.x(), step.y());
        if(physicsData->m_dir == Direction::NONE)
        {
            m_dataRef->m_blackboard.SetPath(path);
            return BTNode::STATE_FAIL; 
        }
        m_dataRef->m_blackboard.SetPath(path);
        return BTNode::STATE_RUNNING;
    }

    return BTNode::STATE_ERROR;
}
```

I don't know why it's behaving like this. Most similar issues I've found online have the problem of calling clear on an empty array, but I have a guard against that, so it shouldn't be the issue.

The other thing I can think of is my Vector2 class requiring some kind of copy constructor or something for when I add elements to the vector, but in the end it's just 2 ints, so I don't know why that might be failing.

I've been over this code too much and might be missing something obvious.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to call `clear()` on an empty vector, the issue is somewhere else, that is, most probably your program has undefined behavior before that code is even executed

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly fine to call `clear` on an empty container of any sort.

Using my psychic debugging skills, I have determined that in code you aren't showing us you're accessing elements of the `vector` that don't actually exist (possibly before you inserted them, and probably with `operator[]`). Usually element creation is done through `resize`, `push_back`, or `insert`.

The other possibility is that you have another memory corruption somewhere in your program.

Comment: Edited to show the full call when it crashes, please have a look.

Comment: @JaimeBarrachina You have to get away from the idea that the place where the code crashes in somehow related to the place where the bug is. It *might* be, but only might. To me your bug sounds like heap corruption, which could have happened in any part of your program. I would look to parts of your program that are allocating memory with new and/or are manipulating pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue I had due to a change in data format. The std::list I was using changed from a pointer to a list to directly the list. This started causing all sorts of errors that checking for the size of the list did not solve and were caused by a ZeroMemory()/memset() call that wiped out all of the tracking data of the list, since it was now part of the class instead of a pointer to the list.

If you have an empty list and call .clear() on it with a crash, chances are you have messed up the internal tracking memory as mentioned by Mark in his answer. Look for a place where you are doing memory clearing on containing classes and the like as the most likely culprits.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 8 years, but I thought too I had this problem when I was destroying an empty bst into which my code was sending a nullptr value to the __p variable in the implementation of "new_allocator.h". This __p is needed to never be null, as mentioned in the file itself!

> // __p is not permitted to be a null pointer.

The solution is not sending anything if you don't have something to send, basically.

Comment: All of this happens in the destructor's implementation, into which I was using indeed a std::list, but the root node was set at nullprt, thus sending a nullptr to __p upon construction of this object.